# Show that $\sum x_n y_n$ converges when $\sum x_n$ is bounded for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\sum (y_n - y_{n+1})$ converges absolutely

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Show that $\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} x_n y_n$ converges when $\sum_{j=1}^{n} x_j$ is bounded for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\sum (y_n - y_{n+1})$ converges absolutely.

Does this actually require an added condition which is "$y_n \to 0 ~\text{as}~ n\to \infty$"? I don't think that it is at all necessary, or did I miss something?

Comment: What if $y_n=1$ for all $n$?

Comment: If you don't think it is necessary, does that mean you have a proof of this problem? You could post that.

Comment: $y_n \to 0$ is necessary as there is a term in the summation by parts that has a $y_n(\sum{x_k})$ form

Comment: @clark It is implicitly assumed that $\sum x_n$ is convergent, so $y_n=1$ is not a counterexample.

Comment: Can it be proven without the 'summation by parts' as Kabo Murphy writes in his answer below?

Answer (score 0):

The hypothesis assumes that $\sum_j x_j$ is convergent. Since $\sum |y_n-y_{n+1}| <\infty$ it is easy to see (by triangle inequality that $(y_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. If $y_n \to l$ then we can prove the result with $y_n$ change to $y_n-l$ and the use convergence of $\sum x_j$ to finish the proof.

For the benefit of other readers let me point out that the result follows when $y_n \to 0$ by a simple 'summation by parts' argument.

Comment: Could you please prove it without the 'summation by parts' as you claim here? Additionally, the hypothesis doesn't assume $\sum x_j$ to be convergent. How about $\{x_n\}^{\infty} = \{1,-1,1,-1,\cdots\}$?

Comment: The hypothesis about $x_n$s is boundedness of the  partial sums $ S_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} x_k$. So you have to write $x_n$ as $S_n-S_{n-1}$ to use this hypothesis. I don't see how you can avoid summation by parts.

Comment: I somehow don't see how taking $S_n - S_{n-1}$ makes more sense. $|S_n| < 2$ $\forall$ $n\in \mathbb{N}$ yet $\{S_n\}$ isn't bounded in the counterexample I stated.